# Having trouble getting world position of object

Tags: opengl, glsl, glut

I have a function called getWorldPosition that is supposed to return a vec3 representing the current position of any VisualObject (a super class I defined).

```
glm::vec3 VisualObject::getWorldPosition()
{
    glm::mat4 totalTransformation = getParentModelMatrix() * modelMatrix;
    return totalTransformation[3].xyz;
} // end getWorldPosition
```

I am trying to use the getWorldPosition function to calculate the distance between two objects in the world.

```
    for (int i = enemiesOnBoard.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        EnemySphere* s = (EnemySphere*)enemiesOnBoard.at(i);
        glm::vec3 sPosition = s->getWorldPosition();
        cout << sPosition[0] << endl;
        for (int j = cannonBallsOnBoard.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
            CannonBall* cb = (CannonBall*)cannonBallsOnBoard.at(i);
            glm::vec3 cbPosition = cb->getWorldPosition();
            GLfloat radiiSum = s->sRadius + cb->sRadius;
            GLfloat distance = calcDistance(sPosition, cbPosition);
            //cout << distance << endl;
            if (distance < radiiSum){
                //cout << "COLLISION BABY!" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that every getWorldPosition is returning a vec3 with 0 for the x,y,z coordinate.

One of the spheres is defined as such,

```
    EnemySphere* s = new EnemySphere();
        enemiesOnBoard.push_back(s);
        s->setShader(glutObjectShaderProgram);
        s->addController(new EnemySphereController(rand() % 8 - 3.5, 1.0));
        s->initialize();
        addChild(s);
```

The relevant controller is this:

```
EnemySphereController::EnemySphereController(GLfloat x, GLfloat r, GLfloat t)
    : Controller(), startX(x), rate(r), translation(t)
{ }

void EnemySphereController::update(float elapsedTimeSec){
    if (translation < 3.9f){
        translation += elapsedTimeSec * rate;
    }
    else {
        target->getParent()->removeChild(target->getObjectSerialNumber());
    }

    glm::mat4 t4;
    t4 = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(startX, -2.50f, translation)); //add 0.5 because the sphere is calculated from the center
    target->fixedTransformation = t4;
}
```

I know this is a complicated problem, but do you guys have any ideas on where I can start?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the world position resides in `glm::vec3(mat[3], mat[7], mat[11])`, so you should change your function to:

```
glm::vec3 VisualObject::getWorldPosition()
{
    glm::mat4 totalTransformation = getParentModelMatrix() * modelMatrix;
    return glm::vec3(totalTransformation[3], totalTransformation[7], totalTransformation[11]);
} // end getWorldPosition
```

The part which you were using as translation is used for projection.